# How does ontouchevent() of edittext work?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to create my custom `EditText` by extending my class to `EditText`. I want to override some touchevents of my custom `EditText`.

Can anyone explain me, how the default touch events for a default `EditText` works? Like when we click on the `EditText`, which `MotionEvent` gets triggered to show the keyboard to input text etc.

I have read the documentation of the EditText, creating a custom view, `onTouchEvent()`, the different motion events like `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE` etc.

I just want to know the working of a default `EditText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the implementation of EditText on Android repository: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/EditText.java.

It looks like EditText inherit onTouchEvent implementation from TextView. You can check how it behave, by looking directly to the code https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L8272.

For example, part of the code responsible for showing keyboard:

```
if (touchIsFinished && (isTextEditable() || textIsSelectable)) {
    // Show the IME, except when selecting in read-only text.
    final InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager.peekInstance();
    viewClicked(imm);
    if (!textIsSelectable && mEditor.mShowSoftInputOnFocus) {
        handled |= imm != null && imm.showSoftInput(this, 0);
    }

    // The above condition ensures that the mEditor is not null
    mEditor.onTouchUpEvent(event);

    handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try it out - override all events you are interested in and display some Log messages (e.g. `Log.i(TAG, "action down");`)

Comment: This will only help to understand current implemenation of onTouchEvent() not how it's implemented in EditText control.